# How to fix the display resolution when using Ubuntu 16 with Acer monitor (with AMD Ryzen 3)?

Tags: ubuntu, screen-resolution

I am using Ubuntu 16.10 on an AMD machine with Ryzen 3 as the processor. Recently, I bought an Acer RO series 24" monitor, and the maximum resolution I can attain is 720 x 968p when my monitor supports 1080 x 1920p. Upgrading to 17 is a prospective solution, but is there a way using 16?

Comment: You should ask this on AskUbuntu or SuperUser. Also I'd not recommend using ubuntu 16.10, it hasn't got support, you should use a supported LTS version or the latest non-LTS supported version.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because *"Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User"* or AskUbuntu.